# Can an ESXi 5.1 VM have Applicaiton Aware Image Processing enabled at the sametime it has Freeze/Thaw Scripts?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, quiesce

So you [can't](http://forums.veeam.com/vmware-vsphere-f24/freeze-script-t21827.html#p110264) enable Application Aware Image Processing at the same time you have Freeze/Thaw scripts enabled.

But in the event that you have a VSS Aware (such as SQL Server 2008 R2) database on the same server as another database that requires the freeze thaw scripts, can you still quiesce by calling it the VSS Aware database using the Freeze/Thaw scripts?